# Unexpected end of multipart data nodejs multer s3

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, multer, multer-s3

iam trying to upload image in s3 this is my code

```
const upload = require('../services/file_upload');
const singleUpload = upload.single('image');
module.exports.uploadImage = (req,res) => {

  singleUpload(req, res, function (err) {
    if (err) {

       console.log(err);
       return res.status(401).send({ errors: [{ title: 'File Upload Error', detail: err}] });
    }
    console.log(res);
    return res.json({ 'imageUrl': req.file.location });
  });

}
```

FileUpload.js

```
const aws = require('aws-sdk');
const multer = require('multer');
const multerS3 = require('multer-s3');
const s3 = new aws.S3();

const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
  if (file.mimetype === 'image/jpeg' || file.mimetype === 'image/png') {
      cb(null, true)
  } else {
      cb(new Error('Invalid Mime Type, only JPEG and PNG'), false);
  }
}

const upload = multer({
  fileFilter,
  storage: multerS3({
    s3,
    bucket: 'image-bucket',
    acl: 'public-read',
    contentType: multerS3.AUTO_CONTENT_TYPE, 
    metadata: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, {fieldName: 'TESTING_META_DATA!'});
    },
    key: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null,"category_"+Date.now().toString()+".png")
    }
  })
})

module.exports = upload;
```

I tried to test api with postmanin serverless local it is giving this error

Error: Unexpected end of multipart data
    at D:\Flutter\aws\mishpix_web\node_modules\dicer\lib\Dicer.js:62:28
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11) storageErrors: []

After deploying online. i tried the api. the file is uploaded in server but its a broken

Answer (score 1):

Are you using `aws-serverless-express`. `aws-serverless-express` will forward original request to Buffer as `utf8` encoding. So multipart data will be lost or error. I am not sure why.

So, I change `aws-serverless-express` to `aws-serverless-express-binary` and everything worked.

```
yarn add aws-serverless-express-binary
```

Hope this help!